Equivalence of two intersecting events
Let $B$ denote the event that a total of $3$ heads were observed when a coin was tossed $10$ times.
Let $A$ denote the event that the first two coin tosses are head when a coin was tossed $10$ times.
The event $A\cap B$ is interpreted as "the first two coin tosses are head and a total of three heads are observed". If I were to introduce an event $C$ and define it as "exactly one out of the remaining $8$ coin tosses is head", would my claim that $A\cap B = A\cap C$ make sense?

If $C$ means "exactly one of the last $8$ is $H$" then yes.  But as you have written it, $C$ might just mean "at least one of the last $8$ is $H$", it's not clear.

I meant exactly one @lulu. I am confused as to what comparison I made between events $B$ and $C$. Is there a mathematical reasoning I may apply to create this equivalence between events $B$ and $C$?, because the way I see it, $B$ and $C$ are two different events and when intersected with $A$ they seem to be equivalent events.

Nobody said $B$ and $C$ are equivalent, they are not.  The claim is that, with the corrected definition of $C$, $A\cap B=A\cap C$ and that claim is true (both sides consist of $HH$ followed by a string of $7,T's$ and $1,H$ in any order).
